# Load a single data from a document in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, crud

How can I find only the "**hotels**" property? *Data in MongoDB-*

```
[
    {
        "picture": "https://d.bcb.ic/dKkqr2da/lalkhal.jpg",
        "name": "Lalakhal",
        "about": "Lalakhal is....",
        "latitude": 25.1048,
        "longitude": 92.1770,
        "hotels": [{}, {}, {}]
    },
    {
        "picture": "https://d.bcb.ic/dKkqr2da/lalkhal.jpg",
        "name": "Lalakhal",
        "about": "Lalakhal is....",
        "latitude": 25.1048,
        "longitude": 92.1770,
        "hotels": [{}, {}, {}]
    },
]
```

*Here is my code*

```
const places = client.db("travel-guru").collection("places");
const hotels = await places.findOne({name: placename})
```

I don't need the all result document. I need just hotels only for a specific document. I am expecting the result-
`hotels = [{}, {}, {}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await places.findOne({name: placename}).project({hotels: 1, _id: 0})`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to this projection document [MongoDB projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

```
const hotels = await places.findOne({name: placename},{hotels: 1})
```

if you don't want id also then

```
const hotels = await places.findOne({name: placename},{hotels: 1, _id:0})
```

Here `1` means that you want that field in the response and `0` means you want to avoid that field in response

Comment: It loads all documents that contain "hotels" property. but I need the hotels only.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the select property to show only required fields.If you want to include _id then you remove _id property from select else it is added in projection by default.

```
const hotels = await places.findOne({name: placename}).select({hotels:1,_id:0});
```

Comment: `.select()` is actually a MongooseJS function, not native MongoDB